# Yup validation: cyclic dependency error with multiple dependent fields

Tags: javascript, validation, formik, yup

I'm using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate 3 fields which are all dependent on each other.
`fieldA`, `fieldB` and `fieldC`. They are numbers and at least one of them needs to have a value > 0.

I'm trying to solve it like this:

```
myFields: Yup.object().shape(
  {
    fieldA: Yup.number().when(['fieldB', 'fieldC'], {
      is: (fieldB, fieldC) =>
        fieldB < 1 && fieldC < 1,
      then: Yup.number().min(
        1,
        'some error message'
      ),
    }),
    fieldB: Yup.number().when(['fieldA', 'fieldC'], {
      is: (fieldA, fieldC) =>
        fieldA < 1 && fieldC < 1,
      then: Yup.number().min(
        1,
        'some error message'
      ),
    }),
    fieldC: Yup.number().when(['fieldB', 'fieldA'], {
      is: (fieldB, fieldA) =>
        fieldB < 1 && fieldA < 1,
      then: Yup.number().min(
        1,
        'some error message'
      ),
    }),
    
  },
    ['fieldA', 'fieldB', 'fieldC']
),
```

This worked fine with only 2 fields `fieldA` and `fieldB`, where each one only had the other field passed in `when(...` but since introducing a third field, I now have a cyclic dependency. Do I need a completely different approach, ie. an external validation function or am I missing some detail here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependencies array is wrong, needs to be [[string, string]], hence you cannot bind all 3 of your fields inside. You have to do it in combinations as

`[['fieldA', 'fieldB'], ['fieldA', 'fieldC'], ['fieldB','fieldC']]`